# Code from subdirectories inaccessible when compiled as C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012

In VS 2012, I made a new Class Library. Under the project root there exists a file Class1.cs. I created a directory under the root called src. Under the src directory, I added a new class MyClass.cs.

```
- MyProject
    - Class1.cs
    - src
        - MyClass.cs
```

When I choose Build --> Build MyProject, it properly creates a DLL in bin/Debug. However, when I try to add this library as a reference in another project, only Class1 is accessible. How can I make MyClass accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the class is public
2. Make sure the class is included in your project!  Simply putting the class in the source tree doesn't work.

Your use of `src` folder betrays your Javaness ... ;)

Comment: The class is now public. Visual Studio indicates that MyClass is part of the project. I'm able to access it via Class1 by using MyProject.src;

Answer (score 1):

Check the namespace of `MyClass` and make sure either it is consistent with `Class1` or it is referenced (i.e. `using`) in your other project. Visual Studio normally adds another *level* in the namespace if you put the file under a sub-folder.